# Get polygon ID from geojson map to highlight table row with corresponding ID

Tags: javascript, html-table, leaflet, geojson

I've created a website which has a geojson map and a html table on it. On the map, I have different polygons with attributes and one of them is an ID. On the table, I've got this information as well. My goal is to highlight the respective table row when you click a polygon on the map (connection through ID via Javascript). How do I get the ID from the polygon the user clicks on (perhaps event handler onclick via Javascript)?

To clarify my problem (Column A is ID column, USER clicks on Polygon with ID 123456789, on map --> popup opens; on html-table --> respective row is highlighted):

[image]

Comment: This example from leaflet itself does give some ideas on how/where to get that ID: https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

Comment: Thank you for yout hint... unfortunately, I'm still not able to "connect" the polygon in the map with the respective row in the table.

Comment: Here is my example of how to connect a geojson using id [linked-view](https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/#29.linked-view)